# No Persistence provider for EntityManager Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am having a `No Persistence provider for EntityManager` exception, and can't figure out what is causing it. Here is my configuration file:

**Persistence.xml** (stored in `src/META-INF`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="HatifimJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>entities.HatUser</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="Benny" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="oracle" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named HatifimJPA
>         at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
>         at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
>         at testing.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:16)

The only difference is that I am trying to get the `EntityManager` into a `public void main(...) { ... }` block, however, I don't recall having a problem doing that in the past.

Can anyone help to point out where my problem might reside?

Comment: Post your exception trace to analyze.

Comment: Is it a desktop app or a webapp?

Comment: It's going to be a webapp, but for now it's just a JPA project with a main class

Comment: I do not see anything wrong but I am not expert; it looks like some configuration issue that prevents the PU from being created. I would try to connect to the DB directly to the ODBC, to check if configuration is ok. Also I would point to where the PU is created/retrieved.

Comment: The listener service was actually down, but I still get the same exception

Comment: Is that the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the persistence.xml to src/main/resources/META-INF/
and put this code to the main method:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HatifimJPA");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence included in the project? It can be found e.g. in hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.4.Final (I use Maven).